# Using the "default" login system for a new MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've just created my first ASP.NET MVC app. Since I didnt choose to create an empty project, visual studio generated some views for me, including a register user page.

But what tables would i need to create to make use of the register/login-functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool to create your membership database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks. Now i just need to figure out how to create the ApplicationServices connectionstring :-)

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to create any user tables at all.  Try and register and you'll see that the first time you do, it takes a little while to complete the operation.  This is because the ASP.NET Membership table structure is being created for you.

However, in Visual Studio, you can go to Project->ASP.NET Configuration which will open a browser window for you to enable you to configure accounts more easily.

If you want to add the ASP.NET Membership tables to your own database, which allows you to add custom tables relating to and extending the functionality of the default membership, you can do so by following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3861834/729541).

Comment: I forgot to mention that im using the adventureworks example db. I ran the tool and the tables were added. Now im getting `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`. But ive added the db to my connetionstring and i can make "normal" EF queries from c# to it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Johan I'm not familiar with the adventureworks samples but try the ideas linked in the last post in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/630ea37d-e497-4dd7-9e8b-85037723363a/).

Answer (score 0):

You must use the ASP.NET Web Administration tools. Official instructions are provided for you here, including information about the database for your users/passwords.

http://www.asp.net/guided-tour/s27.aspx