# Integrating membership tables with my database using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my mvc4 application I have two databases.

1. membership database - I have not changed anything in it. All code is same when we create new project.
2. my database - I have used entity framework to access this database.

Now what I want to do is that I want to include "Membership database" tables in my database & access them using entity framework.

For this I think there will be many changes in code also.
Is there any fast way to do it instead of doing it manually ?

Comment: Maybe this will help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861721/add-asp-net-membership-tables-to-my-own-existing-database-or-should-i-instead-c